Vulkan vertex and UV coordinates incorrectly mapped
I'm using Vulkan to try and render a GLB cube mesh (as a simple example) with a UV texture in my game engine. I've already tried the below to try to map the coordinates to Vulkan space with the SharpGLTF nuget package:
var glb = ModelRoot.Load(glbPath);

var mesh = glb.LogicalMeshes.Single();
var primitive = mesh.Primitives.Single();

var positions = primitive.GetVertexAccessor("POSITION").AsVector3Array().ToArray();
var normals = primitive.GetVertexAccessor("NORMAL").AsVector3Array();
var uvs = primitive.GetVertexAccessor("TEXCOORD_0").AsVector2Array();

var indices = MemoryMarshal.Cast<byte, ushort>(
        indexAccessor.SourceBufferView.Content.Slice(indexAccessor.ByteOffset, indexAccessor.ByteLength))
    .ToArray();

using var mutator = vertexBuffer.CreateMutator(graphicsDevice, commandList);
for (var i = 0; i < positions.Length; i++)
{
    mutator[i] = new Vertex
    {
        Position = positions[i] with { Y = -positions[i].Y },
        Normal = normals[i],
        UV = uvs[i] with { Y = 1.0f - uvs[i].Y },
    };
}

But it really doesn't seem to be working as expected: 
I'm using the default export settings for Blender, and I've made sure the UV unwrap is correct:

And the UV texture is just a simple outline: 
I'm sure there is something simple I'm missing here, but I just don't have the requisite knowledge to figure out what.
The shaders are very simple:
// .vert
#version 450 core
#extension GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects: enable
#extension GL_ARB_shading_language_420pack: enable

layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 normal;
layout (location = 2) in vec2 texCoord;

layout (binding = 0) uniform UBOProjectionView
{
    mat4 proj;
    mat4 view;
};

layout (location = 0) out vec3 fragNormal;
layout (location = 1) out vec2 fragTexCoord;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = proj * view * vec4(position, 1.0);
    fragNormal = normal;
    fragTexCoord = texCoord;
}

// .frag
#version 450 core
#extension GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects: enable
#extension GL_ARB_shading_language_420pack: enable

layout (location = 0) in vec3 fragNormal;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 fragTexCoord;

layout (binding = 1) uniform sampler2D texUVs;

layout (location = 0) out vec4 fragColor;

void main()
{
    fragColor = texture(texUVs, fragTexCoord);
}



Can you share the mesh data you're using — the specific position and UV values for each vertex?

Thank you! This is my glb file, layout and uv files: https://filebin.net/88wab5uuns3kba4u
It was created just by opening Blender, and saving the cube that you get by default as a glb file with default export options

Try using a UV test texture like this one - this can help us diagnose what's going wrong in the UV mapping, since it makes it easier to see which part of the texture is being sampled at each spot.
